# Conditional expectation everywhere non-zero while unconditional one zero?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-expectation

I have a real-valued random variable $X$ that takes on positive and negative values, and

$$E(X)=0 \tag{A}$$

There is also another real-valued random variable $Y$, not independent from $X$, neither $X$-measurable. The underlying probability space is $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$. I considered having

$$E(X\mid Y=y) \neq 0 ,\;\;\; \forall y \in S_Y \subseteq \mathbb R \tag{B}$$

alongside $E\big[E(X\mid Y)\big] = E(X)=0$, where $S_Y$ is the *range* of $Y$.

Initially I thought that the two conditions together could not hold, but that was a knee-jerk reaction, I could not prove anything to that effect, and eventually, it appears natural that they can hold together indeed.

**Nevertheless**, I still sense that there may be not-infrequent, and not "artificial" situations in which, in order for conditions $(A), (B)$ to hold together, some non-trivial additional conditions must also hold. I also conjecture that whether the variables are each discrete or continuous may make a difference.

**EXAMPLES**
**A)** Since we want  $E(X\mid Y=y)$ to not equal zero for all values that $Y$ can take, it means that $0$ is not in its range. Moreover, since $E\big[E(X\mid Y)\big] =E(X) = 0$, it must take on positive and negative values. The two together imply that if the random variable $E(X\mid Y)$ has a probability density function, the latter will have a point of discontinuity at $0$.

**B)**
*If* the bivariate joint distribution of $\{X,Y\}$ belongs to the elliptical class (or to the Pearson family I think), the conditional expectation $E(X\mid Y)$ will be a linear function of $Y-E(Y)$ (not affine, since $E(X) =0$), and then we would have to have that $E(Y)$ does not belong in the range of $Y$ in order to have $E(X\mid Y=y) \neq 0, \forall y \in S_Y$.

**Are there any other situations of some generality, where additional conditions must hold, in order to have both properties $(A), (B)$?**

**Note:** my motive is not a search for theoretical oddities. I have encountered the above situation in the context of my research, as a requirement for the fundamental validity/usefulness of an estimator.

Comment: $E[X\mid Y]$ is a _random variable_ $Z$ that is a _function_ of the random variable $Y$. It just so happens that the _expected value_ of $Z$ is equal to $E[X]$, the expected value of $X$. Now, we are told that $E[X]=0$ and so $Z$ is a zero-mean random variable. Why can't $Y$ be a random variable whose _function_ $Z$ has expected value $0$? Even if $Y$ is nonnegative, its _function_ $Z$ might still have mean $0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I don't disagree - and I already wrote that the two conditions together appear to be able to hold. I just added an example which is not _too_ narrow, since it holds for the elliptical class of bivariate distributions.

Comment: Intuitively, I do not see any paradox in $\{ \ E(X)=0, \ \ E(X|Y) \neq 0, \ \ \forall Y=y \ \}$. Do you have an example where this combination is paradoxical or somehow counterintuitive? **Edit:** OK, I see the example at the end of the post.

Comment: @RichardHardy I do not treat is as a paradox. It just seems ...difficult. I added an example in my question.

Comment: @Zen I just mean for all values in the support of $Y$. Attempted a correction.

Comment: I cannot find any question here.  I think something got lost around "I considered having..."  This is coupled with some mathematical mis-notation that renders some critical objects unintelligible; in particular, "$\{E(X)=0,\;E(X\mid Y) \neq 0\;\;\; \forall\,  y \in S_Y\}$" makes no sense: it is not a valid set constructor and it's difficult to find any clear, unambiguous interpretation of what it is intended to mean.  Would you mind formulating an explicit question that you would like to have answered?

Comment: @whuber With all due respect, I see a clear question, it is in bold letters, and as for the mathematical mis-notation, I have to say that $\{\}$ is not meant only for sets proper, but it is also used to just say "these two relations hold jointly". Now, If no-one else than me sees a clear question, and if everyone else is so confused with my mathematical misnotation -well, too bad for me.

Comment: Alecos: please, don't get pissed off. Try to make your formulation a little  more precise. Let the underlying probability space be $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$. The support of an r.v. $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is the smallest closed Borel set $S_Y$ such that $P(Y\in S_Y)=1$. The conditional expectation $\mathrm{E}(X\mid Y):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is also an r.v. You may talk about $\mathrm{E}(X\mid Y)(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ (or for every $\omega$ outside a set of zero probability). But your "$\forall y\in S_Y$" makes no sense, because $S_Y$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$; it's not a subset of $\Omega$.

Comment: Maybe your question is: suppose that $\mathrm{E}[X]=0$. Is it possible that $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Y]\neq 0$ almost surely for every r.v. $Y$? No, it's not. If $Y$ is equal to a constant almost surely, then $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Y]=\mathrm{E}[X]=0$ with probability one (because in this case $\sigma(Y)=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$, the trivial sigma-field).

Comment: @Zen Or possibly the question is whether (assuming $E[X]=0$) it is possible that $E[X|Y=y]\ne 0$ for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$? Yes, it is.  Alecos, this stark difference in solutions that is made possible by the ambiguity of your notation is why I am asking for clarification. It's not to give you a hard time, but intended only to create a question that has a reasonable chance of being understood in the same way by you, the people who answer, and all other readers.

Comment: @Zen Thank you for the mediation.  Apologies to whuber. I edited the question, hopefully to a more efficient effect.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, Alecos.  I am puzzling over your assertions in (A), because I do not see how your assumptions imply anything about discontinuity of a PDF. For instance, let $Y$ be symmetric about $0$ where $|Y|-1$ has a Gamma(2) distribution and let $X=Y$. (If you insist, this example can be changed into one where $Y$ is not $X$-measurable, but that's just a tangential technical issue.) The support of $Y$ does not include the interval $(-1,1)$, $E[X]=0$ by symmetry, and $E[X|Y=y]=y\ne 0$ for all $y$ in the support.

Comment: @whuber What about the PDF of $E(X \mid Y)$?

Comment: You know that $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Y]=g(Y)$, for some measurable function $g$, and $\int_A Xd\mathbb{P}=\int_A g(Y)d\mathbb{P}$, for every $A\in\sigma(Y)$. Hence, supposing that $Y$ is absolutely continuous, $\mathbb{P}(g(Y)\in B)=\int_B g(y)f_Y(y)dy$, for every Borel set $B$ (in general, $\mathbb{P}(g(Y)\in B)=\int_B g(y)d\mu_Y(y)$, in which $\mu_Y$ is the distribution of $Y$). If you prefer you can transform and find the pdf $f_Z$ of $Z=g(Y)$ and work with it directly: $\mathbb{P}(Z\in B)=\int_B z f_Z(z)dz$.

Comment: Of course, both ways are equivalent due to the theorem known as the "Law of the Unconscious Statistician". Take a look at this also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45441/conditional-expectation-conditional-on-exponential-random-variable